# почему нельзя задать несколько margin, применяемых к одному элементу, в процентах?

Tags: html, css

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Главная</title>
            <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
            <style>


                            .nav1 {
                            font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
                            font-size:0.875em;
                            margin-left:47.803806734992679355783308931186%;
                            margin-top:3.2942898975109809663250366032211‬%;‬
                            }



            </style> 
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="general">
                <header class=""> <!-- 1366 670 -->
                    <img src="01_one_page.png" id="picture1">
                    <nav class="nav1"><pre><a href="#">home</a>       <a href="#">about</a>       <a href="#">work</a>       <a href="#">process</a>       <a href="#">services</a>       <a href="#">testimonials</a>       <a href="#">contact</a>
                    </pre></nav>
                </header>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

данный код невалиден, margin-top:3.2942898975109809663250366032211‬%;‬ не работает, но почему? Как вообще можно классифицировать данную проблему?

Comment: а просто margin-top: 47% незя ?

Comment: Ну... И как это должно работать по вашему? Мне же нужно переместить .nav1 на 3.2942898975109809663250366032211‬% а не на 47%!!!

Comment: вы же сами написали в css margin-left: 47.........% а почему незя написать просто 47% ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, чего Вы рассчитываете достичь такой точностью? Думаете ли Вы, что пользователь сможет углядеть разницу между `47.803806734992679355783308931186%` и `47.8%`?

Во-вторых, Ваше `margin-top` не работает, потому что у родителя нет своей высоты, его высота определяется его содержимым.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.general {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav1 {
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 48.8%;
  margin-top: 13.2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <header class="">
    <!-- 1366 670 -->
    <img src="01_one_page.png" id="picture1">
    <nav class="nav1">
      <pre>
        <a href="#">home</a>
        <a href="#">about</a>
        <a href="#">work</a>
        <a href="#">process</a>
        <a href="#">services</a>
        <a href="#">testimonials</a>
        <a href="#">contact</a>
      </pre>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: также у меня есть

` header {
 margin:0 auto;
 max-width:1366px;
 width:100%;
 height:11.5vh;
}` 
что является предком для .nav1, и, как можете заметить, у .nav1 должна наследоваться высота 11.5vh